# Single-ended digital signal to RS422 differential signal

Tags: differential, rs422, single-ended

I'm trying to control a laser scanner from an Arduino board. The Arduino outputs a single-ended digital signal 0V or 3.3V. The signal I'm transmitting to the laser is the same signal as I use to control a stepper motor, as I want the laser to capture one frame for every step of the stepper.

However, the laser-scanner requires a differential input signal (RS422 compliant). Is there an easy way to convert the single-ended signal to a differential signal?

I've tried to feed the laser input with the single-ended signal, but it picks up a lot of noise.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an rs422 transceiver an example circuit looks like this:[image]
Source:. https://eu.mouser.com/new/maxim-integrated/maxim-max22502e-transceiver/

Comment: A RS422 transmitter only would do.

Comment: Seems like a bit of an overkill.  And why a transceiver?

Comment: @SteveSh: tranceivers are probably much more common than RS422 transmit-only devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could take one side of your RS-422 input to the laser scanner and connect it to an approximately 1.6 V source (formed with a 2-resistor divider network off the Arduino's 3.3 V supply.  Then feed the other side of the RS-422 input with your single ended Arduino output.

This is somewhat of a hack, but should work depending on your noise environment, ground differences, and physical distances between the various pieces of your system.

Comment: I've already tried something similar, a divider that gave 2.5V. without luck. Whys would you try to achieve 1.6V? I don't have the full specs on how the inputs works, but in addition to +/- input lines there is a 0V line that I've connected to the earth terminal on the laser and the 0V of the Arduino).

Comment: Why 1.6 V?  Well, you said the output of the Arduino switches between 0 V and 3.3 V.  So I just took a voltage half way through that range.  If the Arduino really isn't making it to 3.3 V, that may explain why your 2.5 V divider doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what the 0V line is you referenced, unless it's a GND of some sort.  A schematic showing the relevant connection, including supply voltages, returns, and grounds would be helpful.